# Why does moment format in a different timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a day string that looks like this "2013-10-29"

I then have a time string that looks like this "9:00"

If I use moment to format these and generate a date, I keep getting 12 as the time for some reason

```
new Date(moment(day + " " + start).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:m'));
```

> Tue Oct 29 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

How can I use moment to get the local time correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You display a `Date` object and then it's representation depends on the browser. What you're doing is:

1. Creating a `Date` object with `moment()`;
2. Formatting that `Date` with `format()`, now you have string you want.
3. Parsing it back to a `Date`;
4. Converting that date back to string with default `Date.toString()` browser dependant implementation.

This string is what you have and what you need too:

```
moment(day + " " + start).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:m')
```

Do **not** parse it back to a `Date` object (it may even fail, you're using the constructor with `dateString` parameter: see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)), `Date.toString()` will always produce the format preferred by browser.

Comment: so the returned "type" from moment().format is a date object?

Comment: @ToranBillups no, it's a string. Keep a Date until you need to present it to user (and then use format()), a Date object won't keep the format of the dateString it has been constructed from...

Comment: @ToranBillups date->string->date->string chain is meaningless. Keep the first date until you need to convert it (moreover string you provide to Date constructor may fail).

Comment: but if I need a local date (object -not string) what is my best option here? I assumed using moment would save me a ton of hacking but to actually use this in my app it needs to be an instance of date

Comment: @ToranBillups You do not **need** a _local_ date. You **present** a local date. Computations with dates are locale independent (and they take into account time zones too). Let's imagine you have "a" and "b" variables with dates. You can compare them, subtract them. Store them somewhere. Finally after 1000 computations you present result to user and if it's still a date you use format(). No matters where they come from and which format they had when entered by user/computed by system. A date is merely few bytes to store ticks from a reference and sometimes few bits to know the time zone...

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you are looking for is:

```
moment(day + " " + start, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm').toDate()
```

If you need to specify an input format, that goes as a parameter to the moment constructor.  If you use the `format` method, that is the *output* format to create a string.

But Adriano makes some very good points also.  You shouldn't use a `Date` object unless you are passing it to some other code or control that requires it.  End users always need a string for display.

As to *why* your code didn't pick up the time properly, consider that when you used `h:m` that would format as `9:0`.  Some browsers might not understand that as a valid time.  You should have `H:mm` to get `9:00`.  (The `Date` constructor's parsing is implementation specific.)  I also used a capital `H` for 24 hour clock.  If you want to stick to a 12 hour clock, then you should also include an am/pm designator with the format `h:mm a`.